Шаблонизатор Django не распознает шаблоны в веб-странице
Пишу учебный проект по Django (версия Django==5.1.1). Создал обычное приложение "доска объявлений". Тренируюсь в создании шаблонов. Проблема в том, что при запуске локального хоста и обращении к ресурсу, я получаю веб-страницу, но операторы шаблонов не распознаются. Они вставляются в страницу как обычный текст.
Вот файл с настройкой моделей:
mysite/bboard/models.py
from django.db import models

class Bbs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

Файл вьюх:
mysite/bboard/views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Bbs

def index(request):
    bbs = Bbs.objects.order_by('-published')
    return render(request, 'bboard/index.html', {'bbs': bbs})

Сама html-страничка:
mysite/bboard/templates/bboard
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <titlе>Главная :: Доска объявлений</titlе>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Объявления</h1>
    {% for bb in bbs %)
    <div>
        <h2>{{ bb.title }}</h2>
        <р>{{ bb.content }}</р>
        <р>{{ bb.published|date:"d.m.Y Н:i:s" }}</р>
    </div>
    {% endfor %)
</body>

</html>

Настройки путей приложения:
mysite/bboard/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
]

Настройки путей всего проекта:
mysite/mysite/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from bboard.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('bboard/', include('bboard.urls')),
]

Как вяглядит отрендеренная страница - на скриншоте.
Я абсолютно уверен, что записи в таблице есть, так-как проверял это, вставив цикл вывода записей таблицы в функции index().
Кроме того, я тестил тот же код на другом ноутбуке с ОС Elementary OS на браузере Chromium - шаблоны нормально распознаются. Я подумал, что дело в бразуре. Тогда я установил Chromium на своем ноуте, и попробовал запустить с него (сейчас я сижу с файрфокс). Тоже не работает. И на обычном Google Chrome тоже не работает.
Помогите, пожалуйста, в интернете нигде не нашел похожей проблемы. У меня ОС Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS, Python 3.12, Django 5.1.1


У вас в тегах <titlе> и <р> русские буквы затесались, перепишите весь шаблон с нуля с гарантированно английской раскладкой

Ну и ещё вот тут %) скобка очевидно должна быть фигурная, а не круглая

@andreymal, Огромное спасибо, без вас вообще бы не заметил ошибки в html-файле. Мда... Копипастить с pdf-а было очень плохой идеей.
